# Global float array values are not transfering classes

Tags: java, arrays, global-variables

This is a follow up question from [Problem with array assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238690/problem-with-array-assignment)

I now have addcube done like so.. and all works as expected, when I print the array. but when I print the same index's AFTER assignment in another class It tells me their equal to `0`. So the values are not 'saving'. Why is this? How would I correct this?

```
       public void addcube(float highx, float lowx, float highz, float lowz){
        //Constructing new cube...
System.out.println("f = " + f);
        Global.cubes++;
        float y = 1.5f;
        System.out.println("highx = " + highx + "lowx = " + lowx + "highz = " +         highz + "lowz = " + lowz);
        //FRONT
        Global.camObjCoord[Global.i] = highx;
        Global.i++;
        System.out.println("cube i = " + Global.i);
}
```

In both cases I'm printing like so...

```
    int p = 0;
            while(p < 72){
                System.out.println(Global.camObjCoord[p]);
                p++;
            }
```

`Global.i = 0` at the beginning.

The only other places the array is being referenced is the following..

`cubeBuff = makeFloatBuffer(Global.camObjCoord);`

```
                FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr) {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length*4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            fb.put(arr);
            fb.position(0);
            return fb;
    }
```

There is no further refrences to the array in my code.

Thanks.

Comment: We can't tell, because you haven't shown the code that's doing the printing. I very much doubt that it's failing to store the data. I rather suspect you're printing a different index.

Comment: @Meowmix: And what is `Global.i` before the call to `addcube`? You're still leaving us guessing. If you could post a short but *complete* program, I'm sure the reason will become obvious - but you really, really should stop using global variables like this.

Comment: I've updated it with what Global.i is at the start. I think a complete program would be a little large. I'm using the array to dynamically render OpenGL cubes.

Comment: this is now the fourth question about the same addcube() function. perhaps there is a larger issue here that just indices?

Comment: @Meowmix: A complete program doesn't *have* to be large. I'm not suggesting posting it as it is - just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously question your design. You're always refering to that `Global` class, which apparantly seems to be changed from everywhere, and hence you run into such problems (for instance previously with your [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228891/strange-null-pointer-exception)).

Try seperate things clearly using [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) and [do not just use one global state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151768/are-global-static-classes-and-methods-bad) that is operated on by different classes. If classes strictly operate only on their own members then dependencies are reduced and it is much easier to track where data is manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your code looks something like this:

```
System.out.println(Global.camObjCoord[Global.i]);
addcube(/* values here */);
System.out.println(Global.camObjCoord[Global.i]);
```

and it's printing out 0. Well, that's *not* printing out the same index after assignment, because `Global.i` changes value during `addcube`. For example, suppose `Global.i` is 3 before the call to `addcube`. The call to `addcube` will set `Global.camObjCoord[3]` to a value, but then set `Global.i` to 4, so the final line will print out `Global.camObjCoord[4]` - i.e. *not* the value which is just been set.

This sort of thing is precisely why global variables are a bad idea...